# how fix string error in android webview app?

Tags: android, firebase, webview

i am getting this error

> error: method showNotification in class FirebaseMessageReciver cannot
>   be applied to given types; required: String,String,String found:
>   String,String reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in
>   length

**notification.java**

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //handle when receive notification via data event
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"),remoteMessage.getData().get("message"),remoteMessage.getData().get("link"));
        }
        //handle when receive notification
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }

    private RemoteViews getCustomDesign(String title,String message) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title,title);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.message,message);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.icon,R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        return remoteViews;

    }

    public void showNotification(String title,String message,String link){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        String channel_id = "web_app_channel";
        intent.putExtra("link", link);  // add this line for send url
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),channel_id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setSound(uri)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(new long[] {1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send String as params in showNotification.
so send String body and change JSONObject for use.

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //handle when receive notification via data event
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
        }
        //handle when receive notification
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
        }
    }

    private RemoteViews getCustomDesign(String title,String message) {

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title,title);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.message,message);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.icon,R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        return remoteViews;

    }

    public void showNotification(String messageBody){

 try {
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(messageBody);
        String link = jsonBody.getJSONObject("data").getString("link");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        String channel_id = "web_app_channel";
        intent.putExtra("link", link);  // add this line for send url
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),channel_id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setSound(uri)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(new long[] {1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method `showNotification` accept three agrs and you are passing only two params

You need to add the arg for this method  :

> showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());